# pyforms - dynamic styling based on variable value

Tags: python, css, styling, pyforms

I am devloping a [pyform](https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pyforms) control which only accept urls as input.

To achieve this I derivated my class from `ControlText` and added an keypress event handler which tests the current value against a regular expression.

Now i want to somehow change the controls appearance based on a variable like shown in `style.css`.

---

**Controls.py**

```
import pyforms
from   pyforms.Controls import ControlText
import re

class ControlUrl(ControlText):

    def __init__(self, label="", default=None, helptext=None, regex="^((https?:)?\/\/)?(\w+(:\w+)?@)?(((([a-zA-Z\d]{1,2}|[a-zA-Z\d][\w\-]{0,62}[a-zA-Z\d])\.){1,}[\w\-]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3})|([\d:]{2,39}))(:\d{2,6})?(\/[\w.~!+,*:@%-]+)*\/?(\?([\w.~!+%,*:@-]+(=[\w.~!+%,*:@-]+)?)(&[\w.~!+%,*:@-]+(=[\w.~!+%,*:@-]+)?)*)?(#[\w.~!+%,*:@-])?$"):
        self._regex = regex
        super(ControlUrl, self).__init__(label, default, helptext)

    def init_form(self):
        self._pattern = re.compile(self._regex)
        self.key_pressed_event = self.__key_pressed
        super(ControlUrl, self).init_form()

    def __key_pressed(self, event):
        is_url = self._pattern.search(self.value) != None
        self.valid = is_url
```

---

**style.css**

```
#_urlinput[valid="true"] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

---

I would prefer solving it with css but every solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic styling is based on `QPropertys` which can be set with `setProperty` and the css selector looks like `[propertyname=propertyvalue]`

---

**Code:**

```
import sys
import pyforms
from   pyforms.Controls import ControlText
import re


class ControlUrl(ControlText):

    def __init__(self, *args, regex="^((https?:)?\/\/)?(\w+(:\w+)?@)?(((([a-zA-Z\d]{1,2}|[a-zA-Z\d][\w\-]{0,62}[a-zA-Z\d])\.){1,}[\w\-]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3})|([\d:]{2,39}))(:\d{2,6})?(\/[\w.~!+,*:@%-]+)*\/?(\?([\w.~!+%,*:@-]+(=[\w.~!+%,*:@-]+)?)(&[\w.~!+%,*:@-]+(=[\w.~!+%,*:@-]+)?)*)?(#[\w.~!+%,*:@-])?$", **kwargs):
        self._regex = regex
        super(ControlUrl, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def init_form(self):
        self._pattern = re.compile(self._regex)
        self.key_pressed_event = self.__key_pressed
        super(ControlUrl, self).init_form()

    def __key_pressed(self, event):
        self._valid = self._pattern.search(self.value) != None
        base = self.form.lineEdit
        base.setProperty("valid", self._valid)

        #without these lines the style is not applied
        base.style().unpolish(base)
        base.style().polish(base)
```

---

**Css:**

```
QLineEdit[valid=false] {
    border: 1px solid #991903;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
QLineEdit[valid=false]:focus {
    border-color: #db391c;
}
```

---

**More Information:**

- [Basic Pyforms Styling Tutorial](https://pyforms.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0/getting-started/style-layout/)
- [Qt Property System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html)
- [Qt Dynamic Property Styling](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-using-dynamic-properties)